# Pythonic way to generate a pseudo ordered pair list from an iterable (e.g. a list or set)

Tags: python

Given an iterable consisting of a finite set of elements:

> (a, b, c, d)

as an example

What would be a Pythonic way to generate the following (pseudo) ordered pair from the above iterable:

```
ab
ac
ad
bc
bd
cd
```

A trivial way would be to use for loops, but I'm wondering if there is a pythonic way of generating this list from the iterable above ?

Comment: For loops are pythonic.

Comment: Does it need to be pseudo ordered or can it be perfectly ordered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
import itertools
combinations = itertools.combinations('abcd', n)
```

will give you an iterator, you can loop over it or convert it into a list with `list(combinations)`

In order to only include pairs as in your example, you can pass 2 as the argument:

```
combinations = itertools.combinations('abcd', 2)

>>> print list(combinations)
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Comment: did you mean `combinations` instead of `permutations` ?

Comment: Yes I did, fixed.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Python can be such a beautiful (not to mention powerful and expressive) language!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in a list comprehension.

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

output = [(data[n], next) for n in range(0,len(data)) for next in data[n:]]

print(repr(output))
```

Pulling the comprehension apart, it's making a tuple of the first member of the iterable and the first object in a list composed of all other members of the iterable. `data[n:]` tells Python to take all members after the nth.

[Here it is in action.](https://repl.it/NyYe)

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions - they seem to be considered pythonic.

```
stuff = ('a','b','c','d')
```

Obtain the n-digit binary numbers, in string format, where only two of the digits are *one* and n is the length of the items.

```
n = len(stuff)
s = '{{:0{}b}}'.format(n)
z = [s.format(x) for x in range(2**n) if s.format(x).count('1') ==2]
```

Find the indices of the *ones* for each combination.

```
y = [[i for i, c in enumerate(combo) if c == '1'] for combo in z]
```

Use the indices to select the items, then sort.

```
x = [''.join(operator.itemgetter(*indices)(stuff)) for indices in y]
x.sort()
```